# Scribe error "[08S01] Communication link failure"

Tags: scribe

From the **tutorial** session, While I was performing **tutorial no 2** suddenly I face error whole I was trying to modify **data formula**.

The Error is *[08S01] Communication link failure*

I am new in scribe so, unable to understand exactly what's going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So many times ago I face same problem and, 
the problem resolved, I just simply restart scribe, and all done...

But As I am thinking this error may be due to the error in connection to the **ODBC data connection**.

So, in further try to resolve it with **ODBC** connection.....